# Crossing out a text

Tags: java, android, styles

I would like to cross out a text in a `TextView`. So far, I have created a `Style` but I haven't seen anything about crossing the text out. With `android:TextStyle`, it is possible to have the text in bold, italic and bold italic but, apparently, nothing else.

Is there a way to define a `Style` which would cross the text out? Or is there another solution to my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean strikethrough then, just write:

`textview.setPaintFlags(textview.getPaintFlags()
                        | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);`

Comment: or the hard way of using HTML in Java `<html><strikethrough>RANDOMTEXT</strikethrough></html>` and then `textView.setText(stringVariable)`